# Why jQuery If Condition Doesn't Work?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

i am trying to display value in a third textbox by dividing the marks obtained *100/totalmarks;
But i am not able to do that;

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#TextBoxTotalMarks, #TxBx_MarksObtained").keyup(function () {
                var a = parseInt($("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val(), 10);
                var b = parseInt($("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val(), 10);
                var c;
                if (a < b) {
                   c = "sorry not accepted";
                }
                else {
                   c = ((b * 100) / a).toFixed(2);
                }
                $("#TextBoxMarksInPercent").val(c);
            });
        });
```

When i type something like 100 in a total marks textbox and 300 in a marks obtained textbox, i don't see the message "sorry not accepted"

```
  <tr>
                <td class="shade">
                    <asp:Literal ID="Ltrl_TotalMarks" runat="server" Text="Total Marks"></asp:Literal>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTotalMarks" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="shade">
                    <asp:Literal ID="Ltrl_MarksObtained" runat="server" Text="Marks Obtained"></asp:Literal>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TxBx_MarksObtained" runat="server" 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="shade">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Lit_MarksInPercent" Text="Marks In Percent"></asp:Literal>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxMarksInPercent" />
                    <span style="color: black;">%</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: The various answers have found several different issues. I suggest that using any decent, modern web browser, you *walk through* the *client-side* code, setting breakpoints, examining the markup that actually went to the browser, etc., to get an idea of what's actually happening on the client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: *(as of you showing the markup)*

The problem is that the `ID` you give an `asp:TextBox` is not its *client-side* ID. To get that, you need to use its [`ClientID` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx), e.g.:

```
var a = parseInt($("#<%=TextBoxTotalMarks.ClientID%>").val(), 10);
```

---

**Original answer**:

<s>I think [lc.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331605/157247) is probably the main issue</s> *(not since your edit)*, but two other things:

1. Note that you're comparing *strings* (and so `"100"` will be `<` `"30"`). If you mean to compare *numbers*, use `parseInt` on the return values from `val`:

   ```
   var a = parseInt($("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val(), 10);
   var b = parseInt($("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val(), 10);
   ```

   Then you probably want to change your condition slightly:

   ```
   if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b) || a < b) {
   ```
2. Note that `TextBoxTotalMarks` and `TxBx_MarksObtained` should be `id` values, not `name` values. So your inputs should look something like this:

   ```
   <input type="text" id="TextBoxTotalMarks">
   <input type="text" id="TxBx_MarksObtained">
   <input type="text" id="TextBoxMarksInPercent">
   ```

   Or if you want to use `name` instead, change your selectors to be in the form `input[name="TextBoxTotalMarks"]` and similar.

With both of those covered, it works: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/owucug/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/owucug/1/edit) *(I think there's a problem with your calculation, though)*

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: `NaN` is the JavaScript "not a number" value. If you use `parseInt` on something that can't be parsed as a number, the result you get is `NaN`. `parseInt("foo", 10)` for instance. `isNaN(a)` checks whether `a` is `NaN`.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Check the `$("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val()` and `$("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val()` have values in javascript by alert?

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: I've added another possibility (using `id`, where you may be using `name`). Fundamentally, the above works.

Comment: i am using the id, see the html in question

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: Actually, you aren't. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Crowder, thanks. it works for me now. the problem was parsing. Thank your for your precious time

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you meant to also attach the event handler to `#TextBoxTotalMarks`?

```
    $("#TextBoxTotalMarks, #TxBx_MarksObtained").keyup(function () {
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

If you are still getting an issue, you can always set a breakpoint and check what you are getting for `a` and `b`. The problem is most likely a string comparison problem as [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331627/44853) explains.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem here:

```
$("#TxBx_MarksObtained, #TxBx_MarksObtained")
//--^^^^-----------------^^^^-------------------using same selector twice.
```

I think this should be:

```
 $("#TxBx_MarksObtained, #TextBoxTotalMarks").keyup(function () {
```

#### This works for me: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v6Dpm/)

Comment: @DotNetdreamer added a fiddle.